# log4j2 monitorInterval springboot not working

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, log4j2, hot-reload

Im trying to get hot reloading to work with my logging level. The monitorInterval Should do the trick for me, but for some reason it doesnt work.

My log4j2.xml file looks like this:

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="10">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout
        pattern="%d{ISO8601}  [%-12.-12t] %-5p [%12.12X{CorrelationId}] [%-30.-30X{Path}] %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="anywhere" fileName="anywhere.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{ISO8601}  [%-12.-12t] %-5p [%12.12X{CorrelationId}] [%-30.-30X{Path}] %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <logger name="com.cetrea" level="info"/>

    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="anywhere"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Im testing it with my rest api, and when i hit this route, it should print out just LOG.info which it does.

```
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(TokenController.class);

  @RequestMapping(value = "/sensitive-data/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
  public ResponseEntity getData(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
    if (tokenMap.containsKey(token)) {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenMap.get(token));
    } else {
      Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
      LOG.info("Hit with wrong or expired token at " + timestamp + "");
      LOG.debug("debug thing");
      return new ResponseEntity("Token not found, or has expired", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  }
```

Now if i change the level to debug, i would expect it to also print out the LOG.debug, but it doesn't. This doesn't take in effect until i restart the program, instead of it hot reloading 10 seconds later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, when it builds it includes the log4j file, and then reads from that, so the file i was editting wasnt read. I added

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile="Path to the actual file"
```

to the runtime settings and then it worked.